# How to combine a custom formatter with a predefined one in Tabulator JS?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I use Tabulator JS and I have 2 columns with numeric data. For one, I used the built-in `money` formatter with `formatterParams` parameters, for the second, I want to apply exactly the same, with the same parameters, but also add, for example, the color of the cell. How can `formatterParams` be applied in a custom format?

```
new Tabulator("#data-table", {
      data: data,
      layout: "fitColumns",
      columns: [{
          title: "Length",
          field: "length",
          formatter: zeroValueFormatter,
          formatterParams: {
            thousand: " ",
            precision: false
          }
        },
        {
          title: "New length",
          field: "newLength",
          formatter: "money",
          formatterParams: {
            thousand: " ",
            precision: false
          }
        ],
      });


function zeroValueFormatter(cell, formatterParams /* ? */) {
    if (cell.getValue() === 0) {
        cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#add8e6";
    }    
    return cell.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use `rowFormatter` and apply the formatting to the specific column you need.  In your example, the `length` column.  This way you can use the built-in `money` formatter at a column setup level for both columns but apply additional formatting at the row level. Here is an example:

```js
const data = [
  { length: 0, newLength: 10000 },
  { length: 2000, newLength: 20000 },
  { length: 3000, newLength: 0 }
]

const table = new Tabulator("#data-table", {
  data: data,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  rowFormatter: zeroValueFormatter,
  columns: [{
      title: "Length",
      field: "length",
      formatter: "money",
      formatterParams: {
        thousand: " ",
        precision: false
      }
    },
    {
      title: "New length",
      field: "newLength",
      formatter: "money",
      formatterParams: {
        thousand: " ",
        precision: false
      }
    }
  ],
});

function zeroValueFormatter(row) {
  const rowData = row.getData()

  if (rowData['length'] === 0) {
    row.getCell('length').getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#add8e6";
  }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="data-table"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. But what about not in relation to my case, but in general - is it possible to combine `formatter` if necessary?

Comment: Other than using a custom formatter, I am not sure if there is a way to combine built-in formatters.  May be good question for the developers though.